# Catching event in Vue from vanilla script

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a vanilla javascript file that initializes some bootstrap/jquery libraries.

```
function reinitialize() {
    jQuery('.js-datepicker').add('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
}

export {reinitialize}
```

And I call reinitialize method like so in Vue:

```
<script>
    import {reinitialize} from "../../helpers/app";

    export default {
        mounted() {
           reinitilize();   
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I am trying to catch when the datepicker changes which in my vanilla js, I could trigger like so:

```
    jQuery('.js-datepicker').add('.input-daterange').datepicker({
       //...
    }).change(function() {
        alert('do smt');
    });
```

However, using this in my Vue code, it doesn't catch the change event:

```
mounted() {
   $('body').find('.input-daterange').change(function () {
        alert("X");
   })
}
```

---

Then I tried doing something like:

```
    jQuery('.js-datepicker').add('.input-daterange').datepicker({
       //...
    }).change(dateChanged);

   mounted() {
      function dateChanged() {  alert("X")  }
   }
```

However, Vue throws an error that dateChanged is not found.

What is the way of overcoming this problem?

Comment: I guess that it should be something like `$(this.$el).find('.input-daterange').change(..)` in mounted DOM instance..

Comment: How do I declare the `$el` though? It is undefined at the moment

Comment: do you call it inside mounted like `mounted() { $(this.$el).find('.input-daterange').change(..) }`? Or use `.bind(this)` if you want to call it outside function..

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, `this.$el` gets the main parent div of my Vue Component. However, it doesn't trigger on change still. I think this is essentially same with `$('body').find()..` though

Comment: Then try `console.log($(this.$el).find('.input-daterange').length)`

Comment: I made it work. I think when I call `reinitialize()` it was messing the selected element. When I put it under it, it works! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @senty - Now that it works, could you post the working code as an edit or as an answer?  I'm going to be tackling something similar soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code is good. Just **return** the component from your function:

```
function reinitialize() {
    // RETURN STATEMENT IS IMPORTANT
    return jQuery('.js-datepicker').add('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
}

export { reinitialize };
```

In your Vue component:

```
<script>
    import { reinitialize } from "../../helpers/app";

    export default {
        mounted() {
           reinitialize().on('changeDate', function handler() {});   
        }
    }
</script>
```

It is good practice to put event handler inside Vue component. Don't rely on DOM queries to find the element again. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! However, I couldn't make this work. It says `.change()` could not be found

Comment: Oh.. I was just trying to use your code. You need to check how to assign an event handler to jQuery Datepicker. It would be like `reinitialize().on('changeDate', function handler() {})`. Read all the events here at http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html If that is the component you are using.

Comment: @senty, modified my answer. Please try now.